# Bug with overflow-y:scroll and position:absolute in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, overflow, css-position

A DIV is not being rendered (its height remains zero) in Chrome when applying overflow-y: scroll and position: absolute. If any of those is removed, the box is rendered.
This doesn't occur in Firefox.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>Element #1</li>
            <li>Element #2</li>
            <li>Element #3</li>
            <li>Element #4</li>
            <li>Element #5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 31px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#container {
    height: auto;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
}

#container div{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
}

#container div.big{
    height: 500px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle showing the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/351bj7k4/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What caused the problem

Actually it's not a bug.

By using Chrome Developer Tools panel, you'll see that the computed `height` of the `<ul>` element and its parent `<div>` is calculated to `0`.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div>  <!-- <= This -->
        <ul> <!-- <= And this -->
            ...
```

Because a percentage value of `height` property (which is applied to the `<div>`) is relative to the height of its parent.

> **[10.5 Content height: the 'height' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property)**
>
> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's
>   [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block). If the height of the containing block **is not
>   specified explicitly** (i.e., it depends on content height), and this
>   element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'.

As the `<ul>` is removed from normal flow by using absolute positioning, the computed height of the `<div>` would be `0`. And consequently there would be no room for the `<ul>` element which has `bottom: 0` declaration; So the computed height of `<ul>` would be `0` as well.

Hence if you apply `overflow-y: scroll` declaration to the `<ul>`, it hides all the list items as **they all are out of the box**.

## The solution

Thanks to [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) (`display: box` old syntax you've used on the container), `<div>` elements within the `#container` fills the entire height of their parent by default.

Thus, you could **safely remove** `height: 100%` declaration from `#container div` selector which causes the trouble, and also use Flexbox display type for the `<div>` to make the `<ul>` fills the entire height:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/351bj7k4/9/)** *(Another one **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/351bj7k4/10/)**)*

```css
#container div {
    position: relative;
    /* height: 100%; */
    width: 200px;

    display: -moz-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: box;
}
```

---

<sup>PS: In order to check the old answer - which was sort of under a misunderstanding - [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25437095/1).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case, shouldn't height:100% work?

Comment: I have the similar problem.  but I want the the UL elements start from bottom instead of top.   i.e. 'top' is removed.  but as soon as top is removed, the scroll bar disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/4c4crfhb/

Comment: I met the similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55796188/chrome-73-bug-percentage-width-non-static-parent-avoid-children-selves-scrollin